# Improve PostgreSQL - Insert statement execution RUN TIME

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, sql-insert

```
SELECT version() = ('PostgreSQL 12.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit',)
```

I have this use-case where I had to insert records **DAILY** in the `DATAVANT_COVID_MATCH` table while joining 3 other tables.

I’ve created INDEX and also Partitions to decrease the execution time for the Insert SQL but still it’s taking multiple hrs to Insert data into DATAVANT_COVID_MATCH table

**Below is the code that currently runs DAILY**

```sql
    INSERT INTO DATAVANT_O.DATAVANT_COVID_MATCH_{}
    SELECT
    CUST_LAST_NM,
    CUST_FRST_NM,
    CIGNA_DOB,
    CIGNA_ZIP,
    DATAVANT_DOD,
    DATAVANT_DOB,
    DEATH_VERIFICATION,
    DATA_SOURCE,
    INDIV_ENTPR_ID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        CR.PATNT_LAST_NM AS CUST_LAST_NM,
        CR.PATNT_FRST_NM AS CUST_FRST_NM,
        CRD.CUST_BRTH_DT AS CIGNA_DOB,
        CR.PATNT_POSTL_CD AS CIGNA_ZIP,
        MI.DOD AS DATAVANT_DOD,
        MI.DOB AS DATAVANT_DOB,
        MI.DEATH_VERIFICATION,
        MI.DATA_SOURCE,
        CRD.INDIV_ENTPR_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CRD.INDIV_ENTPR_ID ORDER BY CRD.INDIV_ENTPR_ID DESC)
        FROM DATAVANT_O.COVID_PATNT_REGISTRY_DEID CRD
        INNER JOIN DATAVANT_STG_O.MORTALITY_INDEX_{} MI ON
        CRD.TOKEN_1 = MI.TOKEN_1 AND
        CRD.TOKEN_2 = MI.TOKEN_2 AND
        CRD.TOKEN_4 = MI.TOKEN_4
        INNER JOIN DATAVANT_O.COVID_PATNT_REGISTRY CR ON
        CR.INDIV_ENTPR_ID = CRD.INDIV_ENTPR_ID

    ) x
    WHERE
    ROW_NUMBER = 1;
```

```
INDEX:
INDEX created for every partition of MORTALITY_INDEX table and DATAVANT_O.DATAVANT_COVID_MATCH table

example:
CREATE INDEX mortality_index_1941_dod_idx
    ON datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1940 USING btree
    (dod ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default
CREATE INDEX mortality_index_1941_1945_dod_idx
    ON datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1941_1945 USING btree
    (dod ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
etc...
```

```
No of records in each table:
DATAVANT_COVID_MATCH        = 10k
COVID_PATNT_REGISTRY        = 800k
COVID_PATNT_REGISTRY_DEID   = 800k
MORTALITY_INDEX(Total count = 220 Million
MORTALITY_INDEX            ~= 10 Million records for each interval
```

So can someone direct me on how to decrease the execution time to <=1hr ?
Any comments/suggestions are appreciated and Let me know if I need to add any additional information.
Thank you!!!

Below is the EXPLAIN plan for the INSERT statement

```
"Insert on datavant_covid_match  (cost=52885719.27..52885719.44 rows=1 width=271)"
"  ->  Subquery Scan on x  (cost=52885719.27..52885719.44 rows=1 width=271)"
"        Filter: (x.row_number = 1)"
"        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=52885719.27..52885719.37 rows=5 width=57)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=52885719.27..52885719.28 rows=5 width=49)"
"                    Sort Key: crd.indiv_entpr_id DESC"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=21573582.34..52885719.21 rows=5 width=49)"
"                          Join Filter: ((crd.indiv_entpr_id)::text = (cr.indiv_entpr_id)::text)"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=21573582.34..52647701.34 rows=1 width=29)"
"                                Hash Cond: (((crd.token_1)::text = (mi.token_1)::text) AND ((crd.token_2)::text = (mi.token_2)::text) AND ((crd.token_4)::text = (mi.token_4)::text))"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on covid_patnt_registry_deid crd  (cost=0.00..13.20 rows=320 width=145)"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=13011477.77..13011477.77 rows=219629118 width=148)"
"                                      ->  Append  (cost=0.00..13011477.77 rows=219629118 width=148)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1940 mi  (cost=0.00..26129.12 rows=471412 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1941_1945 mi_1  (cost=0.00..89439.94 rows=1615094 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1946_1950 mi_2  (cost=0.00..110751.92 rows=1998492 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1951_1955 mi_3  (cost=0.00..170548.84 rows=3077984 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1956_1960 mi_4  (cost=0.00..228210.95 rows=4120895 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1961_1965 mi_5  (cost=0.00..416877.60 rows=7535260 width=148)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1966_1970 mi_6  (cost=0.00..721723.91 rows=13042691 width=148)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1971_1975 mi_7  (cost=0.00..863088.56 rows=15582656 width=148)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1976_1980 mi_8  (cost=0.00..932241.96 rows=16833796 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1981_1985 mi_9  (cost=0.00..956751.74 rows=17281174 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1986_1990 mi_10  (cost=0.00..972980.59 rows=17920859 width=145)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1991_1995 mi_11  (cost=0.00..1059929.92 rows=19515892 width=145)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_1996_2000 mi_12  (cost=0.00..1147163.44 rows=20842344 width=146)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_2001_2005 mi_13  (cost=0.00..1197933.26 rows=21622326 width=148)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_2006_2010 mi_14  (cost=0.00..925468.03 rows=16956803 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_2011_2015 mi_15  (cost=0.00..1028501.34 rows=19858534 width=149)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_2016_2020 mi_16  (cost=0.00..1065579.24 rows=21352824 width=150)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_2021_2025 mi_17  (cost=0.00..10.80 rows=80 width=398)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on mortality_index_2026_2030 mi_18  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=398)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on covid_patnt_registry cr  (cost=0.00..178937.94 rows=4726394 width=29)"
```

**EDIT: As requested EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
for SELECT**

```
"Subquery Scan on x  (cost=28188731.46..28188731.66 rows=1 width=49) (actual time=38.348..38.348 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Output: x.cust_last_nm, x.cust_frst_nm, x.cigna_dob, x.cigna_zip, x.datavant_dod, x.datavant_dob, x.death_verification, x.data_source, x.indiv_entpr_id"
"  Filter: (x.row_number = 1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=141 read=3"
"  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=28188731.46..28188731.58 rows=6 width=57) (actual time=38.346..38.346 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Output: cr.patnt_last_nm, cr.patnt_frst_nm, crd.cust_brth_dt, cr.patnt_postl_cd, mi_13.dod, mi_13.dob, mi_13.death_verification, mi_13.data_source, crd.indiv_entpr_id, row_number() OVER (?)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=141 read=3"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=28188731.46..28188731.48 rows=6 width=49) (actual time=38.338..38.338 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Output: crd.indiv_entpr_id, cr.patnt_last_nm, cr.patnt_frst_nm, crd.cust_brth_dt, cr.patnt_postl_cd, mi_13.dod, mi_13.dob, mi_13.death_verification, mi_13.data_source"
"              Sort Key: crd.indiv_entpr_id DESC"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=141 read=3"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1018.80..28188731.39 rows=6 width=49) (actual time=38.291..38.291 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Output: crd.indiv_entpr_id, cr.patnt_last_nm, cr.patnt_frst_nm, crd.cust_brth_dt, cr.patnt_postl_cd, mi_13.dod, mi_13.dob, mi_13.death_verification, mi_13.data_source"
"                    Join Filter: ((crd.indiv_entpr_id)::text = (cr.indiv_entpr_id)::text)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=138 read=3"
"                    ->  Gather  (cost=1018.80..27906096.67 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=38.290..39.672 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Output: crd.cust_brth_dt, crd.indiv_entpr_id, mi_13.dod, mi_13.dob, mi_13.death_verification, mi_13.data_source"
"                          Workers Planned: 2"
"                          Workers Launched: 2"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=138 read=3"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=18.80..27905096.57 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=9.141..9.143 rows=0 loops=3)"
"                                Output: crd.cust_brth_dt, crd.indiv_entpr_id, mi_13.dod, mi_13.dob, mi_13.death_verification, mi_13.data_source"
"                                Hash Cond: (((mi_13.token_1)::text = (crd.token_1)::text) AND ((mi_13.token_2)::text = (crd.token_2)::text) AND ((mi_13.token_4)::text = (crd.token_4)::text))"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=138 read=3"
"                                Worker 0: actual time=9.014..9.017 rows=0 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=69 read=1"
"                                Worker 1: actual time=11.521..11.523 rows=0 loops=1"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=69 read=1"
"                                ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..11089723.14 rows=91512134 width=148) (actual time=8.920..8.920 rows=1 loops=3)"
"                                      Buffers: shared read=3"
"                                      Worker 0: actual time=8.689..8.689 rows=1 loops=1"
"                                        Buffers: shared read=1"
"                                      Worker 1: actual time=11.242..11.242 rows=1 loops=1"
"                                        Buffers: shared read=1"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_2001_2005 mi_13  (cost=0.00..1071803.02 rows=9009302 width=148) (actual time=11.240..11.240 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                            Output: mi_13.dod, mi_13.dob, mi_13.death_verification, mi_13.data_source, mi_13.token_1, mi_13.token_2, mi_13.token_4"
"                                            Buffers: shared read=1"
"                                            Worker 1: actual time=11.240..11.240 rows=1 loops=1"
"                                              Buffers: shared read=1"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1996_2000 mi_12  (cost=0.00..1025583.10 rows=8684310 width=146) (actual time=8.687..8.687 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                            Output: mi_12.dod, mi_12.dob, mi_12.death_verification, mi_12.data_source, mi_12.token_1, mi_12.token_2, mi_12.token_4"
"                                            Buffers: shared read=1"
"                                            Worker 0: actual time=8.687..8.687 rows=1 loops=1"
"                                              Buffers: shared read=1"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1991_1995 mi_11  (cost=0.00..946087.22 rows=8131622 width=145) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_11.dod, mi_11.dob, mi_11.death_verification, mi_11.data_source, mi_11.token_1, mi_11.token_2, mi_11.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_2016_2020 mi_16  (cost=0.00..941021.10 rows=8897010 width=150) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_16.dod, mi_16.dob, mi_16.death_verification, mi_16.data_source, mi_16.token_1, mi_16.token_2, mi_16.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_2011_2015 mi_15  (cost=0.00..912659.89 rows=8274389 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_15.dod, mi_15.dob, mi_15.death_verification, mi_15.data_source, mi_15.token_1, mi_15.token_2, mi_15.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1986_1990 mi_10  (cost=0.00..868442.25 rows=7467025 width=145) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_10.dod, mi_10.dob, mi_10.death_verification, mi_10.data_source, mi_10.token_1, mi_10.token_2, mi_10.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1981_1985 mi_9  (cost=0.00..855944.89 rows=7200489 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_9.dod, mi_9.dob, mi_9.death_verification, mi_9.data_source, mi_9.token_1, mi_9.token_2, mi_9.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1976_1980 mi_8  (cost=0.00..834044.82 rows=7014082 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_8.dod, mi_8.dob, mi_8.death_verification, mi_8.data_source, mi_8.token_1, mi_8.token_2, mi_8.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_2006_2010 mi_14  (cost=0.00..826553.35 rows=7065335 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_14.dod, mi_14.dob, mi_14.death_verification, mi_14.data_source, mi_14.token_1, mi_14.token_2, mi_14.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1971_1975 mi_7  (cost=0.00..772189.73 rows=6492773 width=148) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_7.dod, mi_7.dob, mi_7.death_verification, mi_7.data_source, mi_7.token_1, mi_7.token_2, mi_7.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1966_1970 mi_6  (cost=0.00..645641.55 rows=5434455 width=148) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_6.dod, mi_6.dob, mi_6.death_verification, mi_6.data_source, mi_6.token_1, mi_6.token_2, mi_6.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1961_1965 mi_5  (cost=0.00..372921.92 rows=3139692 width=148) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_5.dod, mi_5.dob, mi_5.death_verification, mi_5.data_source, mi_5.token_1, mi_5.token_2, mi_5.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1956_1960 mi_4  (cost=0.00..204172.40 rows=1717040 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_4.dod, mi_4.dob, mi_4.death_verification, mi_4.data_source, mi_4.token_1, mi_4.token_2, mi_4.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1951_1955 mi_3  (cost=0.00..152593.93 rows=1282493 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_3.dod, mi_3.dob, mi_3.death_verification, mi_3.data_source, mi_3.token_1, mi_3.token_2, mi_3.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1946_1950 mi_2  (cost=0.00..99094.05 rows=832705 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_2.dod, mi_2.dob, mi_2.death_verification, mi_2.data_source, mi_2.token_1, mi_2.token_2, mi_2.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1941_1945 mi_1  (cost=0.00..80018.56 rows=672956 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_1.dod, mi_1.dob, mi_1.death_verification, mi_1.data_source, mi_1.token_1, mi_1.token_2, mi_1.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_1940 mi  (cost=0.00..23379.22 rows=196422 width=149) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi.dod, mi.dob, mi.death_verification, mi.data_source, mi.token_1, mi.token_2, mi.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_2021_2025 mi_17  (cost=0.00..10.47 rows=47 width=398) (never executed)"
"                                            Output: mi_17.dod, mi_17.dob, mi_17.death_verification, mi_17.data_source, mi_17.token_1, mi_17.token_2, mi_17.token_4"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on datavant_stg_o.mortality_index_2026_2030 mi_18  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=398) (actual time=6.825..6.825 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                            Output: mi_18.dod, mi_18.dob, mi_18.death_verification, mi_18.data_source, mi_18.token_1, mi_18.token_2, mi_18.token_4"
"                                            Buffers: shared read=1"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=13.20..13.20 rows=320 width=145) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=0 loops=3)"
"                                      Output: crd.cust_brth_dt, crd.indiv_entpr_id, crd.token_1, crd.token_2, crd.token_4"
"                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB"
"                                      Worker 0: actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1"
"                                      Worker 1: actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=1"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on datavant_o.covid_patnt_registry_deid crd  (cost=0.00..13.20 rows=320 width=145) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=3)"
"                                            Output: crd.cust_brth_dt, crd.indiv_entpr_id, crd.token_1, crd.token_2, crd.token_4"
"                                            Worker 0: actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=1"
"                                            Worker 1: actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on datavant_o.covid_patnt_registry cr  (cost=0.00..213480.43 rows=5532343 width=29) (never executed)"
"                          Output: cr.covid_patnt_regstry_sv_key, cr.cret_ts, cr.indiv_entpr_id, cr.patnt_frst_nm, cr.patnt_last_nm, cr.patnt_brth_dt, cr.patnt_gendr_cd, cr.patnt_st_cd, cr.patnt_postl_cd, cr.patnt_dth_dt, cr.covid_idfd_frm_clm_ind, cr.covid_idfd_frm_lab_ind, cr.frst_diag_dt, cr.hosp_ind, cr.frst_covid_admsn_clm_event_key, cr.frst_covid_admsn_refined_clm_event_key, cr.frst_covid_icu_admsn_refined_clm_event_key, cr.frst_fllwup_clm_ln_key, cr.frst_fllwup_clm_svc_beg_dt, cr.subscrbr_indiv_entpr_id, cr.pre_covid_clncl_case_key, cr.post_covid_clncl_case_key, cr.prim_covid_diag_cd, cr.prim_covid_diag_dt, cr.sec_covid_diag_cd, cr.sec_covid_diag_dt, cr.frst_vacnn_dt, cr.sec_vacnn_dt, cr.vacn_manfctrer_nm, cr.load_ctl_key, cr.ingest_timestamp, cr.incr_ingest_timestamp"
"Planning Time: 4.229 ms"
"Execution Time: 40.007 ms"
```

**DDL for Mortality Table**

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE datavant_stg_o.mortality_index
(
    data_source character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    op_directive character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dd_imp_flag integer,
    dod date,
    dob date,
    death_verification integer,
    gender_probability double precision,
    gender character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    token_1 character varying(44) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    token_2 character varying(44) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    token_4 character varying(44) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    token_5 character varying(44) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    token_7 character varying(44) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    token_16 character varying(44) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    token_key character varying(44) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
) PARTITION BY RANGE (dod);
```

Comment: I think not only partitioning is not helping but also slows down your query in this scenario, It has added two more step ( append , hash) to your query plan. what are the type of Token1 ... Token4 columns ?

Comment: also if you give us output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` we can judge better

Comment: Very often `distinct on ()` is faster than an equivalent query using window functions.

Comment: @eshirvana I learned that ANALYZE actually executes that INSERT statement so should i add ROOLBACK: at the end as it says in here?-> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html

Comment: @Mando just do it for the select

Comment: @eshirvana thank you just added the plan

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for commenting, can you elaborate,  how to achieve this i.e adding DISTINCT() for columns from multiple tables?

Comment: @eshirvana also added DDL to answer your question regarding Tokens

Comment: It seems unlikely that the DBMS is going to realize that what you want is a max value when you express it by saying number the rows of a subquery then just keep the 1st. Characterize the rows you want, don't say how to calculate them in steps. Also default index order is asc, but you partition desc, so you are generating rows in the opposite order of fast access. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Please research & act on how to ask a good SQL & good SQL performance question in [so] & [dba.se] & their metas.

Comment: well, your second explain shows the query went parallel and It took only 40 ms , which is great , so now I think we need to find out why it didn't go parallel on your insert .

Comment: @eshirvana ohh.. I see

Comment: @eshirvana Could you able to sense what's going on with the Insert? Will it be helpful if we try to achieve this by creating a VIEW?